# <img> taking too long to load, using jQuery and Slides plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, slideshow

I'm using jQuery 1.6 and the Slides plugin ([slidesjs.com](http://slidesjs.com))
The slides have this format: `<a><img></a>`
The image of the first slide takes up to 6 seconds to load.
From the Chrome network panel I know that the image is being loaded twice, and one of the loads is what is taking so long.

The code that creates the slideshow is:

```
$('.rotator').slides({
  preload: true,
  play: 7000,
  pause: 2500,
  hoverPause: true
});
```

In the screenshot you'll see a reference to jquery-1.6.js @ line 2206, which is:

```
attr: function( elem, name, value, pass ) {
  ...
  elem.setAttribute( name, "" + value ); // <-- line 2206
```

Chrome's network information:
[image: chrome's network info]

Any ideas of what is happening and how can avoid this?

Comment: That's network time taken to retrieve the image. Nothing you can do about it. It's properly cached after first load as well, so nothing to improve there either. Slow connection? Crap web host? Can be many things, but nothing to do with jQuery or your code.

Comment: Code 304 means that the file hasn't changed since last request. You aren't downloading image data twice

Answer (score 2):

I would be interested in seeing a link to what you've built already. There's so many things that could be looked at for optimization such as:

- Many HTTP requests
- Image size
- Amount, size, and position of external scripts on page

etc

If there's only a few images being displayed on page load you should make sure the other images don't try to download until the page is fully loaded, as you will be stealing available resources from higher priority elements.